# jOOQ problems with limit..offset - no values sets

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am trying to build a query using jOOQ,  this is my test code:

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.DERBY);
String query = create.select().from(TABLE).limit(1).offset(0).getSQL()
```

I get as query:

```
select field1, field2...fieldN etc from TABLE offset ? rows fetch next ? rows only
```

the problem is `?` in `? rows fetch next ? rows only` it seems to ignore the values that i used in limit and offset to build the query, why?

I am trying to select the first row from the results and I am using jooq 3.4.1

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Query.getSQL()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL--) returns your SQL string with `?` as placeholders for your bind variables. The idea is that you can feed this statement to a `PreparedStatement` and then explicitly bind all variables, which are available through [`Query.getBindValues()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getBindValues--).

You can also have jOOQ inline all your bind variables, by calling [`Query.getSQL(ParamType)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL-org.jooq.conf.ParamType-) as such:

```
String sql = query.getSQL(ParamType.INLINED);
```